# Text to Join Mobile Connect Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

I'm currently implementing MobileConnect and we came across a duplicate contact issue.  When the user text JOIN to our shortcode it creates a contact on the mobile subscriber table.  Since we need to identify these users we will send a daily import file with additional user data that will be merged on another DE that we will send SMS messages from.  This process is creating a dup contact.  My question is there a way to merge this data so it doesn't create a duplicate contact or is it possible to directly update the initial mobile subscriber table with a query that pulls the file data into this table?